Generating WAV files with a MaryTTS generated audio
I try to record a WAV file with a MaryTTS generated audio.
The code I am using is:
package org.marytts;

import marytts.LocalMaryInterface;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import marytts.exceptions.MaryConfigurationException;
import marytts.exceptions.SynthesisException;
import marytts.util.data.audio.AudioRecorder;

public class MaryTTSWav {
   static {
     CodeSource codeSource = MaryTTSWav.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
     URL url = codeSource.getLocation();
     File file = new File(url.getFile()).getParentFile();
     System.setProperty("mary.base", file.getPath());
   }
   private LocalMaryInterface maryI;
   private float volume = -1f;
   private float rate = -1f;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MaryTTSWav wavRecorder = new MaryTTSWav();
      wavRecorder.record("this is a test");
   }

   public MaryTTSWav() {
      init();
   }

   private void init() {
      try {
         maryI = new LocalMaryInterface();
         maryI.setVoice("enst-camille-hsmm");
         //setVolume(2);
         //setRate(1);
      } catch (MaryConfigurationException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void record(String sentence) {
      try {
         AudioFileFormat.Type targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
         AudioInputStream stream = maryI.generateAudio(sentence);
         AudioFormat audioFormat = stream.getFormat();

         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
         TargetDataLine targetDataLine = null;
         File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
         File targetFile = new File(dir, "toto.wav");
         try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            AudioRecorder.BufferingRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder.BufferingRecorder(targetDataLine, targetType, targetFile,(int) 10000);
            System.out.println("Recording...");
            recorder.start();
            try {
               recorder.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Recording stopped.");
         } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     } catch (SynthesisException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

   private void setVolume(float volume) {
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
      buf.append("Volume(amount:").append(volume).append(")");
      maryI.setAudioEffects(buf.toString());
   }

   private void setRate(float rate) {
      StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
      buf.append("Rate(durScale:").append(rate).append(")");
      maryI.setAudioEffects(buf.toString());
   }
}

As you see I generate an audio with a sentence, producing an AudioInputStream. Then I use the WAVE format to record this audio on a .wav file. The execution also does not emit any StackTrace
I have a resulting .wav file, and it appears to be valid (I am able to play it without any problem with VLC for example), but it has no sound. Why?
